# definition and example of standard topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology, definition

> Let $X$ be a topological space. Then
>
> trivial topology $T$ is $\{\phi,X\}$
>
> discrete topology $T$ is the family of all subsets of $X$.
>
> standard topology $T$ is the collection of all open intervals of $X$?

I understand the trivial and discrete topologies but I don't know how to approach to the standard topology. Can someone give me a simple example of standard topology?

Comment: The trivial topology is also called the indiscrete topology. FYI.

Comment: The trivial topology is also called the anti-discrete, or coarse topology.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no such thing as the standard topology on any set $X$. If $X=\mathbb R$, then the standard topology is the topology whose open sets are the unions of open intervals. More generaly, if $X\subset\mathbb R$, then the standard topology is the topology whose open sets are the unions of sets of the type $(a,b)\cap X$, with $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $a<b$.