# Query with common words used to describe topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently studying an introduction to Topology Course and commonly find a topology to be described as "usual" or "standard". What does this mean?

Also regarding the complex plane, what topology can we equip it with, my first thought was:

$\mathscr{T}_{\mathbb{C}}:=\{\mathbb{B}(a,r)|a\in\mathbb{R},r>0\}$

However this doesn't contain the empty set. I could just add it with a union to get:
$\mathscr{T}_{\mathbb{C}}:=\{\mathbb{B}(a,r)|a\in\mathbb{R},r>0\} \cup{\emptyset}$

but surely there is a better defined topology to equip $\mathbb{C}$ with.

Comment: Any finite intersection of the balls must also belong to the topology. As for the other question, you describe what is a "standard" topology on certain sets, like $\mathbb{R}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2757928/418131

Comment: I see. I can't think of a topology. Do you know any topologies to equip C with?

Comment: Well no the one you described works. Take two non intersecting balls. Indeed, the same argument may apply for the whole set $X$ (union of all balls). The set you have given serves as a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for the topology on $\mathbb{C}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Usual" and "standard" are not technical terms; they mean the topologies that mathematicians most typically consider on various things, and you pick them up as you do more mathematics. A typical example is the "usual" topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, which in both cases is the [Euclidean topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology) induced by the Euclidean metric.

So the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}$ is the topology whose open sets are arbitrary unions of open balls. The collection of sets you've described isn't a topology because it isn't closed under union.